# How can I convert a variable 120VAC-600VAC to 120VAC without using a large transformer?

Tags: power, transformer, mains

I have been asked to design a circuit that is able to convert from several possible input voltages (120VAC, 208-240VAC, 400VAC, 600VAC) to a single output voltage (120VAC.)

The output needs to be able to power 4 GFCI outlets at 20A each.

So far, the only thing that I have found that might work is a 10KVA transformer with a manual switch for input voltage selection.

The problem is that this transformer is huge and costs $1200. I need a cheaper and lighter circuit. Does anyone know of anything that could help me out?

I have looked into converting to DC and using an inverter but I haven't been able to find inverters that take a variable high voltage input.

Comment: should your title read 12VAC, or 120VAC? A bit of a difference.

Comment: As soon as there is a cheaper reliable solution it will be used.

Comment: I don't know of any products that would work offhand, though keep in mind asking for product recommendations is against the rules here; this Stack is primarily concerned with electronics design. I can't imagine there's any way to design such a device for much less than, not only $1200, but even ten times that.

Comment: I think 10kW of power supply for 1200 dollars is quite reasonable. I don't think you're going to find something much cheaper.

Comment: @Neil_UK You're right thanks for the catch.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am not asking for product recommendations so much as circuit recommendations. For example rectification and SMPS.

Comment: @user1850479 Doesn't mean I shouldn't look and ask questions.  I have been updating old designs for the last month and a half. Saved $1000s by swapping out unnecessary transformers for SMPS.

Comment: Well, as I'm hinting at, sure a basic scheme like that may work -- but you'll spend hundreds of hours perfecting such a thing, not to mention hundreds of blown transistors and other materials. Hundreds still to make something marketable -- that passes regulatory standards for surge, emissions, etc. Is there budget/justification for such a thing, or is it just a one-off?

Comment: If you go AC-DC-AC, you'll probably be in the ~80% efficiency range, which means you will have a 2kW space heater on your hands so after the heatsink and fans you're probably not going to be saving any space with this method.

Comment: The right answer is to pushback on the requirement.  "four 20A GFCI outlets" seems like a Pointy Haired Boss requirement and you should find out what the loads actually are. It's a lot cheaper when you can size it to the loads actually to be served, instead of planning for a worst case.  Note the transformer needs to be larger than 10 kVA because when you're on a low tap, there's more current on the primary.  You're not going to be able to series/parallel the primary between more than 2 sizes.  Also, what about frequency? Do they need 60Hz?

Comment: @vir might save me from having to spec the in enclosure heater they want me to add.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes its going to be at 60hz. I also think that the outlet requirement is a little ridiculous. i feel like it was sprinkled on top as a sales thing without understanding what it would require. I am in essence working to create a product that has already been sold to a customer as a concept.

Comment: The enclosure heater might not be that bad, since you could simply PWM to that. But since you NEED 60Hz, you have no choice but to go AC/DC/AC, and that equipment will be all the enclosure heat you need :)